Gnosis safe API - Gnosis Balance USD request
API request to get our balances in USD doesn't seem to work on gnosis
part of my personnal adress request :
[
  {
    "tokenAddress": null,
    "token": null,
    "balance": "1013236706779756816",
    "ethValue": "0.0",
    "timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "fiatBalance": "0.0",
    "fiatConversion": "0.0",
    "fiatCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "tokenAddress": "0x9C58BAcC331c9aa871AFD802DB6379a98e80CEdb",
    "token": {
      "name": "Gnosis Token on xDai",
      "symbol": "GNO",
      "decimals": 18,
      "logoUri": "https://safe-transaction-assets.safe.global/tokens/logos/0x9C58BAcC331c9aa871AFD802DB6379a98e80CEdb.png"
    },
    "balance": "100047891271498896",
    "ethValue": "0.0",
    "timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "fiatBalance": "0.0",
    "fiatConversion": "0.0",
    "fiatCode": "USD"
  },

and request url using from https://safe-transaction-gnosis-chain.safe.global/ is :
https://safe-transaction-gnosis-chain.safe.global/api/v1/safes/myAddress/balances/usd/?trusted=false&exclude_spam=false

Thanks!

What exactly you want to achieve ?

I want to obtains USD value of my gnosisSafe like the interface :)

Can you add the parameters that you’re passing while calling the request url, including address, etc. ?

This URL seems to work on my end; could you pass the exact request, the response and the expected behaviour please? Thanks in advance, Louis

https://safe-transaction-gnosis-chain.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0xeC247b0Ca0c1c84e3a5e5f55589AE3844e7c259a/balances/usd/?trusted=false&exclude_spam=false
@Louis-SafeCoreTeam
and for the answer. i have tokens quantity, but token value USD show "0" like my first message !

Oh right, the Safe Price Service is not actively maintained anymore and is left to the community to be further developed. It might not be active on every network through Safe Transaction Service
